# Running AppleScript to control the app Spectacle (Shift+Opt+right arrow)

Tags: keyboard, applescript, shortcuts-app

I am trying to set up a shortcut to open two apps, then position them on-screen. There doesn't appear to be a way to run a Hotkey command within shortcuts. So I have opted to try my hand at AppleScript, in hopes of making up for its lack of capability.

The shortcut reads as follows:
Open Console
Run AppleScript with App
Open Logic Pro
Run AppleScript with App

For the first script, I need to tell the app Spectacle to perform "left arrow+option+control"
For the second script, I need to tell the app Spectacle to perform "right arrow+option+control" then "right arrow+shift+option+control"

Here is the code I tried to put together, although it is probably laughable.

```
tell application "Spectacle"
    keycode 123 using {option down, control down}
end tell

tell application "Spectacle"
    keycode 124 using {option down, control down}
    keycode 124 using {shift down, option down, control down}
end tell
```

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated, thank you in advance!